# Access DOM on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the textContent of a `a` tag inside an `ul` tags. The problem is that when I access the console returns me "null" instead of the element. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Hope you ca help me and thanks.

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnDLv.png)

[JS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYNIW.png)

On other hand, the console returns me HTMLColletion but I can't get anything from there because I don't know the syntax to get the things from there, all I get is "undefined".

```
<div class="dropdown">
         <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="resumen" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Productos 0 | Precio 0€ </a>
                <ul id="productos" class="dropdown-menu">


                </ul>

            </li>

         </ul>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var resumen2 = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link dropdown-toggle");
var resumen =  document.getElementById("resumen");
console.log(resumen);
console.log(resumen2.textContent);
```

Comment: Paste your code in your post directly.

Comment: here it is, sorry.

Comment: `document.getElementById("resumen").textContent`? You don't need to grab the elements by class _and_ the element by id if the element with the id is the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `script` tag at the end of the body, or add a `defer` attribute to it.

Comment: Thank you so much Steven Spungin, appreciated.

Comment: You did not show the script tag in your example.  Did this solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, well you solve it, thank you. Only was need it to put the script tag on html on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `getElementsByClassName` returns a **NodeList object**, not an **Element object**.

Use `resumen2[0].textContent` to get the content of your element.

```js
var resumen2 = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link dropdown-toggle");
var resumen =  document.getElementById("resumen");
console.log(resumen);
console.log(resumen2[0].textContent);
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
         <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="resumen" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Productos 0 | Precio 0€ </a>
                <ul id="productos" class="dropdown-menu">


                </ul>

            </li>

         </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementByClassName return a node list.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
         <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="resumen" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Productos 0 | Precio 0€ </a>
                <ul id="productos" class="dropdown-menu">


                </ul>

            </li>

         </ul>
</div>
<script>
var resumen2 = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link dropdown-toggle")[0];
var resumen =  document.getElementById("resumen");
console.log('resumen',resumen);
console.log('resumen2.textContent', resumen2.textContent);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below domo,

https://jsfiddle.net/jf60754y/

**HTML Code:**

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Get a tag text</title>
    <body>
     <a id="gettext" href="#">hellow Mr shiva</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**JS Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('gettext').innerHTML
</script>
```

As per you js code,

`innerHTML` not available folowwed by the `document.getElementById('resumen')`